# Places to host Java WAR projects for a portfolio? Cheap or Free

Tags: java, hosting, war, free, portfolio

Does anybody know of any sites that let you host java .war project files for free or cheap?

I want to host some applications for a portfolio, so I'm not looking for the most robust service.
I'm aware of the free credit with AWS and GCS, but looking for something more long-term.

Alternatively, any ideas on showcasing projects for a portfolio?

Thanks

Comment: Not the right kind of question for this site but Java hosting is seldom free or cheap as it's relatively resource-intensive. I would host it yourself. You'd learn and save a lot

Comment: Host it yourself and use ngrok if you don't want to buy a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

- https://www.back4app.com/
- https://render.com/

This offers java deployment as docker
samle dockerFile https://github.com/rksharma1401/apache-camel-microservice/blob/main/Dockerfile

Comment: These are perfect! Thank you 